ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS (nginx + Hetzner load balancer + Cloudflare)
I would like to set up a Hetzner Load Balancer for my server with nginx application.
And I have the following configuration.
Load Balancer of Hetzner:

Origin server with app nginx as a target.
Nginx configuration:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.test2.mydomain.com;
    return 301 https://www.test2.mydomain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name  www.test2.mydomain.com;
  root /var/www/my_projektpublic_html/web;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com-0001/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com-0001/privkey.pem;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dh2048.pem;

  ssl_session_timeout 5m;

  ssl_session_cache shared:TLS:2m;
  ssl_buffer_size 4k;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;" always;

  include "conf.d/server_ssl.conf";
  include conf.d/live.conf;
  include conf.d/php_fpm_status.conf;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.log main;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx-error.log;


  proxy_read_timeout 300;
  proxy_connect_timeout 300;
  proxy_send_timeout 300;

}


DNS A records point to the load balancer's IP address.
SSL/TLS encryption mode is Full
Edge Certificates Advanced
Page rule in Cloudflare:

test2.mydomain.com/*
Forwarding URL (Status Code: 301 - Permanent Redirect, Url: https://www.test2.mydomain.com/$1)

I get error:
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS 
and SSL doesn't work properly and httpstatus shows 521 error.
If I bypass the load balancer and send traffic to the origin server, the website works.
I tried disabling a redirection on nginx, Cloudflare but without success. The same error.

I hope this can help anyone.
The ssl connection is handled by the loadbalancer, thats why you configure the ssl certificate directly in the load balancer, so in your nginx you must only handle plain http connection only the server block listen 80, delete the 443 server block and all definitions like paths or root place it in the 80 block.
The too many redirects is because you are trying to redirect port 80 to https and back again to the load balancer.
try it and let me know.
Should be something like
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.test2.mydomain.com;
    root /var/www/my_projektpublic_html/web;
}

